# Unable to Import From main Java Directory Into test Directory (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, android, firebase, intellij-idea, kotlin

After I attempted to add the [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-quick-start.html) library to my project for testing, some configuration in my project changed and I cannot import any classes from my **main** package into my JUnit **test** package.

My Main Class runs as expected, but I am unable to run any tests requiring Classes from the main package.

I've tried the following:

- Removing AssertJ import
- Rebuild Project
- Refresh All Gradle Projects
- Invalidate IntelliJ cache an Restart from Settings
- Deleting project locally and re-downloading from GitHub
- Removing testing directory and re-adding

Looking at another project that is working it appears to be an issue with my **build.gradle file**

```js
group 'carpecoin'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.0.3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // JUnit Jupiter API and TestEngine implementation
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    // To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code
    testCompileOnly('org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0')
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line below in the **build.gradle** file was failing causing the issue above.

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'`

I updated Firebase to the following and now it is still causing an issue when running tests. It appears to run fine in production:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`